# How to read a property file from different jar file resource in Apache Camel

Tags: apache-camel, jbossfuse

Is there any technique to read a property file from a different jar file resource folder in Apache Camel

I have two project one is ESB-tracker and other is ESB-common. queue-config.properties is place under ESB-common/pk/com/herman/common/resources/.

ESB-common is a simple java project and ESB-tracker in a fuse-integration project in which im trying to read this property file using the below line.

```
<propertyPlaceholder id="properties" location="pk/com/herman/common/resources/queue-config.properties"/>
```

I have deployed the both jar files in jboss fuse but i got below excpetion

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Properties file pk/com/herman/common/resources/queue-config.properties not found in classpath
```

Comment: 1. did you try to define path as `location="classpath:/pk/...` 2. when you open your ESB-common.jar directly (i.e. with zip) do you see your file in exact path as you defined from root? 3. Is ESB-tracker a WAR file and ESB-common.jar available to the ESB-tracker class loader?

Comment: 1. yes i have also tried `location="classpath:/pk/...` 2. Yes properties file is present in ESB-common.jar 3. ESB-tracker is a JAR file and ESB-common is available for ESB-tracker as both are deployed in JBoss fuse deploy folder

Comment: If path inside ESB-common.jar is correct it means that ESB-common.jar is not available to the Camel Context Class loader. I cannot say more because I use Spring beans for property files and keep them in the file system outside of any jars/wars. Sorry...

Comment: You need to export the package where the config file is from that bundle, and then import that package from the other bundle where you want to read it from. That is standard OSGi classloading with package import / export. Then you should be able to read it from the classpath.

Comment: thanks @ClausIbsen, imported ESB-common resource package in ESB-tracker. It worked